# Can't figure out how to use mathdotnet LevenbergMarquardtMinimizer

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, nuget, math.net

I'm trying to use the Mathdotnet [LevenbergMarquardtMinimizer](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/LevenbergMarquardtMinimizer.htm) to find the roots of a system of equations f1 and f2. For other optimizers it seems like a pretty straightforward process - you call Minmize() with the functions you're using, an initial guess, constraints, etc., and get a result.

Mathdotnet however uses an [IobjectiveModel](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/IObjectiveModel.htm) as the first parameter, I assume to pass the functions.

I'm kind of stumped as to what to do here, since there are no examples of the code in the documentation and I can't find any online. My best guess is that I'm supposed to create an implementation of the IObjectiveModel interface for my functions, and then pass that to the minimize() function. However I really hope this is not necessary as it looks like a lot more work for something that isn't really needed in other optimization packages.

Has anyone encountered this before and could offer some clarification? I was really surprised at how many downloads this package has on Nuget, without there being really any example code for it online.

I haven't tried overriding the interface yet because I'm not sure if it's needed. when I implemented this in Python (with scipy) I was allowed to pass the minimized functions as parameters to the method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey there - my code shouldn't be relevant to this issue, I'm trying to figure out how to set up a base case

Comment: You can read the tests to see how it should be used.  e.g.:  https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/e010de79d70f197112cdc86d2e637f5db2968d24/src/Numerics.Tests/OptimizationTests/NonLinearCurveFittingTests.cs#L56